# Temporary Table

Tags: sql, temporary

Can I create temporary table within case statement..?

if yes please explain me with example.

actually I want to do something like this..

```
declare @a int = 1

select case when @a = 1 then
'yes'
else
'no'
end
```

if first case execute then I would like to create temp table with that condition which is require to manipulate some business data.

in else case I would like to create another table with other condition to manipulate business data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two interpretations of what I believe you can mean:

**Have columns with different data:**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN @a = 1 THEN
         'yes'
       ELSE
         'no'
       END AS answer
INTO tempTable
```

**Create a table with different queries:**

```
IF @a = 1
  SELECT 'yes' AS answer
  INTO tempTable2
ELSE
  SELECT 'no' AS answer, 'other field' as other
  INTO tempTable2
```

[SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7227e/1).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should use `IF` instead of `CASE`:

```
declare @a int = 1

IF @a = 1
BEGIN
    'yes'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    'no'
END
```